# Will deleting/flagging my own post give me back my reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, self-delete

I created a post which was down-voted multiple times. If I delete or flag my post and it is deleted by a moderator, will I get my reputation back?

Comment: Yes you will get your rep back.  But it also paves the way to a [question ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), which is assessed automatically based on a undisclosed algorithm that calculates your contributions to the site (and it includes all posts both deleted and not deleted).  For users with low rep,  even just a couple highly downvoted and deleted posts might be enough to trigger the ban.  So basically do not delete too many and you should be ok.

Comment: Just looking through your question history, you may which to reread the [What to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) section of the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).  Questions about software unrelated to programming are off-topic and you have several posts where your questions are on-topic for [su] but not Stack Overflow.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Do you think it would make sense for self-deletion to be a positive? We do encourage reducing the noise.

Comment: @bjb568 one deleted question won't do it.  In my experience, it usually takes several, so if someone has to delete enough highly downvoted posts, then you have to wonder if they really understand the scope of the site, and you have to wonder if they have bothered to learn after the first deletion.

Comment: Hm… yes, but the person is still better than one who doesn't delete h(is|er) posts. I wonder how you'd make new users learn about the site… a more intrusive how-to-ask? A "You're last question got closed, please review it" messages like with flags? It's an interesting problem.